# Decrease horizontal scroll width for BasicTextField in compose

Tags: android, input, android-jetpack-compose, horizontal-scrolling

In Jetpack Compose I am using `BasicTextField` and I want to add my own `horizontalScroll` for it. When I apply it, it seems to have built in minimum width, so even if content fits, user is still able to scroll.

[image: Scrolling behaviour when horizontalScroll is added]

I don't have this issue if I remove horizontal scroll and use `singleLine = true` mode. Then `BasicTextField` becomes scrollable only when entered value doesn't fit.

Is there any way to add some sort of "wrap content" flag for horizontal scroll?

The implementation is pretty standart, I add horizontal scroll to it like this:

```
var scrollState by remember { mutableStateOf(ScrollState(0)) }
BasicTextField(
    modifier = Modifier
        .horizontalScroll(state = scrollState, reverseScrolling = true),
singleLine = true,
...
```

Comment: I also have the same problem. Were you able to find any solution?